# Running Spark history Server at Context localhost:18080/sparkhistory instead at port localhost:18080

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cloudera, databricks, apache-spark-2.0

I want to run Spark history server at localhost:18080/sparkhistory instead at localhost:18080.

The end goal is to access Spark History Server with a domain name i.e,  domainname/sparkhistory

is there any hacks or spark config options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i can tell path is hardcoded as "/history" (see org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer `val UI_PATH_PREFIX = "/history"`), so i dont think you can, unless you somehow modify this file.
You can try to setup nginx server which will forward your request to history server with config like this

```
server {

server_name domainname;

location /sparkhistory/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:18080/;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    sub_filter "/static/" "/sparkhistory/static/";
    sub_filter '<a href="/' '<a href="/sparkhistory/';
    sub_filter_once off;
}
}
```